# What is a good Algebraic topology reference text?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Learning Roadmap for Algebraic Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89843/learning-roadmap-for-algebraic-topology)

The title of the question already says it all but I would like to add that I would really like the book to be about more algebraic topology than its applications : it should contain theorems' proofs. Just adding that I have never taken a course on algebraic topology, I'm a bachelor student, so a "beginner" book style will be very good!!! Also mentioning what would be the prerequisites for mastering the branch is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hatcher is readable and free online http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html

Comment: see also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84409/best-algebraic-topology-book-alternative-to-allen-hatcher-free-book

Answer (score 3):

A very good book is J. Frank Adams, *Algebraic Topology, a student's guide*.

But I started learning Algebraic Topology using the book *Topolgy* by JAMES R. MUNKRES. I think this is good for beginners because it was good for me as a beginner.

You might also consider *Algebraic Topology* by Allen Hatcher.

For prequisite,  you will need Point-set topology and I strongly recommend *Topology* by James R. Munkres or *Topology without Tears* by Sidney A. Morris.

Answer (score 2):

My first exposure to algebraic topology was [Massey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902716), followed by [Hatcher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521795400), [Rotman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387966781) and [May](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226511839). I'm now studying [Spanier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387944265) and [Dieck](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3037190485). You'll probably want to supplement these with good books in Homological Algebra and Category Theory. As for prerequisites, you'll need a good background in Point-Set Topology.

This [bibliography](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATbib-ind.pdf) contains most if not all of the good books in algebraic topology at various levels, as well as a nice collection of important articles in the field.