# Sites or youtube videos to learn algebraic topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, self-learning, education, fundamental-groups

Can anyone recommend any good videos, short courses or sites (preferably not full lectures) on algebraic topology? Something similar to the videos of the YouTube channels The Bright Side of Mathematics or 3B1B would be ideal. It seems there is a shortage of beginner-friendly videos on algebraic topology available on YouTube.

Essentially, I'm looking for videos that offer an intuitive foundation for concepts in algebraic topology, without the need for excessive rigor. I'm a complete beginner and I've just finished a course on metric spaces. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this learning roadmap](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89843/learning-roadmap-for-algebraic-topology), not necessarily all by video. But I suppose you can also read a book, or some slides.

Comment: Have you atleast had a course on set topology? Otherwise I don't see a point in starting algebraic topology (although arguably algebraic topology had earlier beginnings starting with Euler than set topology). The reason is that to at all talk about even the basics like a path-connected space, you need topological notions of connectedness, continuity etc which all courses on algebraic topology will assume. Technically, algebraic topology is usually taught as a second course (or after half a semester in a really advanced course) to topology.

Comment: Or atleast if you have seen complex integration, then I suppose the notion of homotopy atleast won't seem too outlandish.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I've had a course on basic set topology, it taught concepts such as compactness, connectedness, completeness etc, I've also had a course on basic complex analysis which includes eg cauchy's theorem

Comment: I suggest [this course](https://youtu.be/SXHHvoaSctc) on Youtube. It's not that rigorous, but it's fun and very simple to understand.